# JFrame.setsize() not doing anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For some reason, I can't seem to get this to work:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hi");
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

No matter what size I pass to setSize(), the resulting window when I run the program is still tiny. Any suggestions?

Comment: is this your complete code? Because this should work just fine (it does for me). Are you sure you're not calling `frame.pack();` somewhere?

Comment: For me it is working what is the issue?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  The problem would seem to be in code that is **not** shown above.  Note that GUIs should be created and changed on the EDT.

Comment: Verify that your program is compiling and you are running the newly compiled code. Code snippet you have pasted seems to work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this code,will get you a JFrame. and look setPrefered method in the program

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameDemo {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("");
        jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(jlbempty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));`  Guesses (as to the size).  Add an `EmptyBorder` of the required size and stop having to guess.  See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)